# Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am trying to save OAuth tokens for a chrome extension. I have created a page where a javascript code runs which fetches the tokens from the URL and saves them to chrome's local storage. It was working fine until recently and now when it redirects to that page, it displays an error `Requests to the server have been blocked by an extension.` When I manually refresh the page, the error is gone and the script works fine. I tried `location.reload()` w/o `true` & setting `location.href` in the javascript code, nothing seems to be working.

[image: screenshot of the error]

I have two questions

1. How to avoid this error?
2. Is there a better to store OAuth credentials? The documentation seems to be outdated.